# How to create custom device android graphical layout tool?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

So I am developing for the Kindle Fire HD and have a question about Eclipse. I am using the graphical layout tool in Eclipse to generate xml, however, the Kindle Fire HD is not under the available devices for screen type, therefore, when I run it on the Kindle, everything is off a little bit. So basically my question is how do I create a custom device? I have the screen resolution. Just to clarify further by create a custom device I am talking about a custom sized screen that I can add layouts, buttons, labels, etc. Thanks in advance!